# ValueError: Could not interpret metric identifier: loss using Keras and Scikeras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, scikeras

i want to use GridSearchCV using KerasClassifier, but i am stuck at the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[54], line 42
     38 model = KerasClassifier(model=create_model, verbose=1)
     40 grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, scoring='accuracy',error_score='raise')
---> 42 grid_search_result = grid_search.fit(X, y)
     44 print("Best Parameters:", grid_search_result.best_params_)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:874, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    868     results = self._format_results(
    869         all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
    870     )
    872     return results
--> 874 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    876 # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable
    877 # self.scoring the return type is only known after calling
    878 first_test_score = all_out[0]["test_scores"]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:1388, in GridSearchCV._run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1386 def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1387     """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1388     evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:821, in BaseSearchCV.fit.<locals>.evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    813 if self.verbose > 0:
    814     print(
    815         "Fitting {0} folds for each of {1} candidates,"
    816         " totalling {2} fits".format(
    817             n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits
    818         )
    819     )
--> 821 out = parallel(
    822     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    823         clone(base_estimator),
    824         X,
    825         y,
    826         train=train,
    827         test=test,
    828         parameters=parameters,
    829         split_progress=(split_idx, n_splits),
    830         candidate_progress=(cand_idx, n_candidates),
    831         **fit_and_score_kwargs,
    832     )
    833     for (cand_idx, parameters), (split_idx, (train, test)) in product(
    834         enumerate(candidate_params), enumerate(cv.split(X, y, groups))
    835     )
    836 )
    838 if len(out) < 1:
    839     raise ValueError(
    840         "No fits were performed. "
    841         "Was the CV iterator empty? "
    842         "Were there no candidates?"
    843     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py:63, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
     58 config = get_config()
     59 iterable_with_config = (
     60     (_with_config(delayed_func, config), args, kwargs)
     61     for delayed_func, args, kwargs in iterable
     62 )
---> 63 return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1863, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1861     output = self._get_sequential_output(iterable)
   1862     next(output)
-> 1863     return output if self.return_generator else list(output)
   1865 # Let's create an ID that uniquely identifies the current call. If the
   1866 # call is interrupted early and that the same instance is immediately
   1867 # re-used, this id will be used to prevent workers that were
   1868 # concurrently finalizing a task from the previous call to run the
   1869 # callback.
   1870 with self._lock:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1792, in Parallel._get_sequential_output(self, iterable)
   1790 self.n_dispatched_batches += 1
   1791 self.n_dispatched_tasks += 1
-> 1792 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1793 self.n_completed_tasks += 1
   1794 self.print_progress()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py:123, in _FuncWrapper.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    121     config = {}
    122 with config_context(**config):
--> 123     return self.function(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:686, in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, split_progress, candidate_progress, error_score)
    684         estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    685     else:
--> 686         estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    688 except Exception:
    689     # Note fit time as time until error
    690     fit_time = time.time() - start_time

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py:1491, in KerasClassifier.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
   1489     sample_weight = 1 if sample_weight is None else sample_weight
   1490     sample_weight *= compute_sample_weight(class_weight=self.class_weight, y=y)
-> 1491 super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)
   1492 return self

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py:760, in BaseWrapper.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    755 kwargs["epochs"] = kwargs.get(
    756     "epochs", getattr(self, "fit__epochs", self.epochs)
    757 )
    758 kwargs["initial_epoch"] = kwargs.get("initial_epoch", 0)
--> 760 self._fit(
    761     X=X,
    762     y=y,
    763     sample_weight=sample_weight,
    764     warm_start=self.warm_start,
    765     **kwargs,
    766 )
    768 return self

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py:928, in BaseWrapper._fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, warm_start, epochs, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    924 X = self.feature_encoder_.transform(X)
    926 self._check_model_compatibility(y)
--> 928 self._fit_keras_model(
    929     X,
    930     y,
    931     sample_weight=sample_weight,
    932     warm_start=warm_start,
    933     epochs=epochs,
    934     initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    935     **kwargs,
    936 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py:536, in BaseWrapper._fit_keras_model(self, X, y, sample_weight, warm_start, epochs, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    532 except ValueError as e:
    533     # Keras puts keys like "val_accuracy" and "loss" and
    534     # "val_loss" in hist.history
    535     if "Unknown metric function" not in str(e):
--> 536         raise e
    537 self.history_[key] += val

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py:531, in BaseWrapper._fit_keras_model(self, X, y, sample_weight, warm_start, epochs, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    529 for key, val in hist.history.items():
    530     try:
--> 531         key = metric_name(key)
    532     except ValueError as e:
    533         # Keras puts keys like "val_accuracy" and "loss" and
    534         # "val_loss" in hist.history
    535         if "Unknown metric function" not in str(e):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/utils/__init__.py:111, in metric_name(metric)
    105 if not (isinstance(metric, (str, Metric)) or callable(metric)):
    106     raise TypeError(
    107         "``metric`` must be a string, a function, an instance of"
    108         " ``tf.keras.metrics.Metric`` or a type inheriting from"
    109         " ``tf.keras.metrics.Metric``"
    110     )
--> 111 fn_or_cls = keras_metric_get(metric)
    112 if isinstance(fn_or_cls, Metric):
    113     return _camel2snake(fn_or_cls.__class__.__name__)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/metrics/__init__.py:204, in get(identifier)
    202     return obj
    203 else:
--> 204     raise ValueError(f"Could not interpret metric identifier: {identifier}")

ValueError: Could not interpret metric identifier: loss
```

I tried everything, uninstalled all packages and installed them again. Changes the specified losses and metrics but nothing changed i am still stuck. Any help is much appreciated. Here is the code for reference:

```
def create_model(dropout_rate=0.2, hidden_layers=1, neurons=64):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    
    for _ in range(hidden_layers - 1):
        model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    return model

param_grid = {
    'model__neurons': [10, 20],
}

model = create_model()
model = KerasClassifier(model=create_model, verbose=1)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, scoring='accuracy',error_score='raise')

grid_search_result = grid_search.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: I was just dealing with the same "Could not interpret metric identifier: loss" error with KerasClassifier (in VSC). I googled and found your question. In my case, I uploaded my notebook to google Colab, and it ran without error there. Therefore it's probably a problem with libraries installations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it also on kaggle but its throws the same error there

Comment: Now that you mentioned, I tried Kaggle for curiosity, and I'm surprised to see the same error on Kaggle, but not Colab!

Comment: Thats weird, i didnt find a solution as of now and just implemented the wrapper myself

Comment: It seems to be related to a library or installation issue.

Comment: I suggest trying it in the Google Colab environment, and if it is successful then use the same packages for your local environment

Comment: It seems it is a package version issue. It works for me with Python 3.10.11 and the following packages:: folium==0.14.0
imblearn==0.0
ipykernel
jupyter
keras==2.15.0
mapclassify==2.6.1
matplotlib==3.7.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
numpy==1.25.2
openpyxl==3.1.2
pandas==1.5.3
pydot==1.4.2
PyQt5==5.15.10
scikeras==0.12.0
scikit-learn==1.2.2 
tensorflow==2.15.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.15.0
tensorflow-hub==0.16.1
tensorflow-metadata==1.14.0
tensorflow-probability==0.23.0
urllib3==2.0.7